# How to find the .desktop files for pinned applications in the Unity launcher?

Tags: unity, unity-dash, .desktop

I know the desktop files live in
`/usr/share/applications` and `~/.local/share/applications`. I'm looking for 2 information:

1. Where can I see the desktop items that show in my launcher (I would love to have right-click properties on the launcher)

Update: Moved this part of my question [to another entry](https://askubuntu.com/questions/188001/finding-desktop-files-based-on-their-titles) to be able to give credit:

"When I type into the Dash applications show up with their title, how can I find the associated desktop file (again right click is missing)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know which applications are pinned currently (from other launcher icons, which are also shown in the launcher) , you can use gsettings

Open a terminal and use this command

```
gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites
```

This command gives me the output below, (the exact output may differ)

```
['nautilus-home.desktop', 'firefox.desktop', 'libreoffice-writer.desktop', 'libreoffice-calc.desktop', 'libreoffice-impress.desktop', 'ubuntu-software-center.desktop', 'gnome-terminal.desktop', 'wimaxcmgui.desktop', 'synaptic.desktop']
```

The .desktop files are with the exact name in the output. But, you may not see the name though.

You can use `cp` command to copy them in some other directory.

- First use this command to get a variable `list` with the list of .desktop files which are pinned.

  ```
  export list=`gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites | grep .*.desktop | tr "[]\'," " "`
  ```
- Then copy those files in your Desktop.

  ```
  cd /usr/share/applications && cp $list ~/Desktop && cd
  ```

Hope this will help. You now have the .desktop files which are pinned in your desktop.

Comment: Works partially. If you have application in ~/.local/share/applications they are not copied. But that's easy to solve (and was the bonus part of the answer anyhow). Thx for helping

Comment: @stwissel thanks. you can do this by first copying files from local dir and then copying from system dir (without replacing). **But,** I though, you just wanted to have them to  edit so the system ones are good for that.

Comment: (I confused gsettings and gconf (again), and made a bad comment.  Wiped it; sorry.)