# How can I find out what .desktop file is being launched?

Tags: unity-dash, .desktop

I've used `click install` and `click register` to install a click app on Ubuntu (not Ubuntu Touch). The version was 0.5.1.

Now, a new version (v0.5.6) is available and I installed it using the same method.

I know the new version is installed because the `current` directory points to `0.5.6`:

```
$ ll /opt/click.ubuntu.com/com.ubuntu.developer.mdspencer.ubuntu-tasks/
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  4 clickpkg clickpkg 4096 Oct 18 10:19 ./
drwxr-xr-x  8 clickpkg clickpkg 4096 Sep 13 21:22 ../
drwxr-xr-x 10 clickpkg clickpkg 4096 Sep 13 20:01 0.5.1/
drwxr-xr-x 10 clickpkg clickpkg 4096 Oct 18 10:19 0.5.6/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 clickpkg clickpkg    5 Oct 18 10:19 current -> 0.5.6/
```

However, when I launch the application from the Dash, the about page still shows v0.5.1.

So my question is, how can I find out where the `.desktop` file that I'm launching resides so I can understand why the correct version isn't being launched? I'm also simply curious to learn where the click `.desktop` files live. Is there some tool that shows where a given `.desktop` file is, or is there a way to see the equivalent to `$PATH` for `.desktop` files?

*Note: this is similar to, but not a duplicate of, [How to find the .desktop files for pinned applications in the Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187381/how-to-find-the-desktop-files-for-pinned-applications-in-the-unity-launcher?rq=1)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to find the path of a `.desktop` file based off of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/187394/109543), which is similar but not quite what I wanted.

First, pin the app in question to the Launcher. Then, run the following command:

```
gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites
```

In my case, the output was:

```
['application://nautilus.desktop', 'application://firefox.desktop', 'application://thunderbird.desktop', 'application://chromium-browser.desktop', 'application://libreoffice-writer.desktop', 'application://libreoffice-calc.desktop', 'application://ubuntusdk.desktop', 'application://gnome-terminal.desktop', 'application://gedit.desktop', 'application://com.ubuntu.developer.mdspencer.ubuntu-tasks_ubuntu-tasks_0.5.1.desktop', 'application://xchat.desktop', 'unity://running-apps', 'unity://expo-icon', 'unity://devices']
```

So the name of the `.desktop` file is:

```
com.ubuntu.developer.mdspencer.ubuntu-tasks_ubuntu-tasks_0.5.1.desktop
```

Which shows what my problem is. Regardless, you can find where that `.desktop` file is by running `locate`:

```
$ locate com.ubuntu.developer.mdspencer.ubuntu-tasks_ubuntu-tasks_0.5.1.desktop
/home/mspencer/.cache/upstart-app-launch/desktop/com.ubuntu.developer.mdspencer.ubuntu-tasks_ubuntu-tasks_0.5.1.desktop
/home/mspencer/.local/share/applications/com.ubuntu.developer.mdspencer.ubuntu-tasks_ubuntu-tasks_0.5.1.desktop
/home/mspencer/.local/share/click/hooks/desktop/com.ubuntu.developer.mdspencer.ubuntu-tasks_ubuntu-tasks_0.5.1.desktop
```

Which shows where the app is being launched from.

I'm not exactly sure what caused my problem, but I fixed it by running `click unregister` and then `click register` for the latest version.